# Handling Session with JSON

Tags: django, django-models

From my webservice (REST) Im returning the following JSON values when an user authenticated successfully.

```
result= simplejson.dumps( 'emailId':user.USER_EMAIL_ID, 'userId':user.USER_ID, "firstName":user.USER_FIRST_NAME})
```

I want to handle session in the website

```
serviceRequest  = requests.post(ServiceSettings.getUserLoginURL(), headers = headers, data = json.dumps(payload))
objUser = serviceRequest.json ()
login (request , objUser) # from django.contrib.auth - to manage session
```

but i'm getting the following error

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to search in your database for the user with ID `objUser['userId']` and the pass that `User` instance to `login` function (instead of passing `objUser`).